# Parse XML objects to HTML ul element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

This is the response XML from a webservice:

```
<information>
    <customer>
        <customer_id>asdf1_id</customer_id>
        <customer_name>asdf1</customer_name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customer_id>asdf2_id</customer_id>
        <customer_name>asdf2</customer_name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customer_id>asdf3_id</customer_id>
        <customer_name>asdf3</customer_name>
    </customer>
</information>
```

And, I need to fetch each customer, and parse it into an HTML `<ul>`.

So basiclly, the webservice returns this XML with 1, 2, 3, 4, or whatever the quantities of customers, and I need that the AJAX parse this information
to the `<ul>` html element, that should look like this:

```
<li onclick='UpdateCustomer(asdf1_id)'>asdf1</li>
<li onclick='UpdateCustomer(asdf2_id)'>asdf2</li>
<li onclick='UpdateCustomer(asdf3_id)'>asdf3</li>
```

So, what is the AJAX code that I need to parse the XML response to `<li>` objects inside the `<ul>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "information.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(response) {
            $('customer', response).each(function() {
                $(".ulcontainer").append($("<li onclick=UpdateCustomer(" + $(this).find("customer_id").text().trim() + ")>" + $(this).find("customer_name").text() + "</li>"));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="ulcontainer">

</ul>
```

Basically put your XML into a file `information.xml` and use a `GET` request to fetch your data.  When the data is successfully fetched, use the jQuery `each` function to loop through each of your `customer` tags and get the information within them.

EDIT: I modified my AJAX call to give you the desired `<li>` markup that you described above.